# Click Listener on Table cell not callin the on click method?

Tags: android, onclick, tablelayout

I created a table by inflating rows programatically and tried setting on click listener to each views in those rows but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my inflator and how i call my click method.

```
  inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {

        TableRow row = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.week_view_cust,
                t_layout, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.time_week_tv);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll1);
        ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll2);
        ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll3);
        ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll4);
        ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll5);
        ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll6);
        ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll7);
        (new CustomListener()).onClick(ll);
        tv.setText("" + time[i]);
        t_layout.addView(row);

    }
```

And this is my click listener class.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.time_ll1:

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.time_ll1);
        TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setTextSize(12);
        tv.setTextColor(000000);
        Log.i("============", "success");
        tv.setText("hello");
        ll.addView(tv);
        break;

    case R.id.time_ll2:
        break;
    case R.id.time_ll3:
        break;
    case R.id.time_ll4:
        break;
    case R.id.time_ll5:
        break;
    case R.id.time_ll6:
        break;
    case R.id.time_ll7:
        break;
    }
```

what am i doin wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should set the **onClickListener** for each LinearLayout like this:

Guessing that CustomListener is implementing your onClick() method

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll1);
ll.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener());
ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll2);
ll.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener());
ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll3);
ll.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener());
ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll4);
ll.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener());
ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll5);
ll.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener());
ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll6);
ll.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener());
ll = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.time_ll7);
ll.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener());
```

Comment: Thanks :) the Log is updated in the Logcat but the textView is'nt being created ....any idea y?  and why is,nt my way of implementing the click listener not working?

Comment: You creating new instance of CustomListener() for every element, that's unnecessary and will use a lot of memory

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see you didnt set `onClickListener`
You need to call `ll.setOnClickListener(this);` for every cell

Comment: btw, what did you mean by `(new CustomListener()).onClick(ll);` ?

Comment: CustomListner() is my class tat implements onclicklistener